# How to calculate the exact packet rate of HDL-64E S3D?

Tags: lidar, ros-kinetic, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using velodyne hdl-64e s3d with this driver (https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne), however, this driver only support up to S2.

Can anyone tell me how to calculate the exact packet rate of HDL-64E S3D?

---

It's 5780.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297461/how-to-calculate-the-exact-packet-rate-of-hdl-64e-s3d?/) by [Richard Guan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33609/richard-guan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-07-16**:
This looks like a cross-post of https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/175 . I'm a bit surprised that the packet rate isn't in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's 5780.

---

Originally posted by [Richard Guan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33609/richard-guan/) with karma: 38 on 2018-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [debonair](https://answers.ros.org/users/37218/debonair/) on 2018-11-16**:
do you know how many points are generated per second for 64E_S3D?